# Hide button if number is less than 0

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to hide button if the number is `<=` 0.

My code:

```
<?php 
        $sst = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM students_records WHERE LRN=:uID AND SRN=:sd");
    $sst->bindparam(":uID",$id);
    $sst->bindparam(":sd",$srn);
    $sst->execute();
    $sstRow=$sst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $dsst = $sstRow['Date'];
    $sdsst = strtotime($dsst);
         echo "
        <script>
        var checkStatet = function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'q_check_diffex.php?od=$sdsst'
  }).done(function(data){
      var button1 = jQuery('#rbtntimep');
      var o = data.diffex;
    var time = jQuery('#rbtntime');
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
  time.html(o);
  o--;
  if(data.diffex <= 0) {
      button1.hide();
jQuery('#quizsb').click();          
  }
}, 1000)

  });

}

checkStatet();
        </script>
        "
        ?>

<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="rbtntimep"  style="float:right;" disabled><span id="rbtntime"></span></button>
```

**q_check_diffex.php**:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_GET['od'])){
    $deotd = $_GET['od'];
}
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$cdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());
$scdate = strtotime($cdate);
$rscdate = $scdate + 10;

$e = $rscdate - $deotd;

// You would calculate a real value here
echo json_encode([
  'diffex' => $e
]);
?>
```

I tried the above code but it do not hide the button if `<=` 0

Comment: Try placing your script after you have defined your button.

Comment: Try code of this link:- https://eval.in/890541  (don't go for output just use the code instead of yours) . Try and let us know worked or not?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, It started with `1509515800`, & to check I have to wait for 1509515800 secs.

Comment: what do you mean? I din't get you?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Value of `<span id="rbtntime"></span>`

Comment: @AlivetoDie , I hope in your code, `$sdsst` have stored any other value instead of value from database.

Comment: @dorado It didn't work.

Comment: you need to pasre json response in your ajax code.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Which response?

Comment: `data` inside `done` function

Comment: @AlivetoDie Can you help me with the code?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Any updates..?

Comment: @NamarsahaMNetworking   After `url: 'q_check_diffex.php?od=$sdsst',` add `dataType:'JSON'` and check

Comment: @AlivetoDie It is not hiding after `10s`

Comment: @NamarsahaMNetworking  now i am unable to help

Comment: @AlivetoDie I tried, `url: 'q_check_diffex.php?od=$sdsst', dataType:'JSON'`

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the response in JSON from q_check_diffex.php

So, before using `var o = data.diffex;`, you need to convert the response into object.

Just add the following code right after `done(function(data){`

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now you can fetch the values like you are using in the code `var o = data.diffex;`